# Shortest path analysis has unattainable vertices in result from PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-network-analysis

You can try this code directly in the console. It basically finds the shortest path but I only have unattainable vertices in the result.

Do you know how I can correct this?

My layer consists of MultiLine geometries.

```py
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
segmentLayer = layers[0]
loggerLayer = layers[1]

features = segmentLayer.getFeatures()
# self.features(features)

director = QgsVectorLayerDirector(segmentLayer, -1, '', '', '', 3)

crs = segmentLayer.crs()

transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(loggerLayer.crs(),crs, QgsProject.instance())

builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)

# graph = builder.graph()
pStart = QgsPointXY(677725.236666,6155028.577216)
#pEnd = QgsPointXY(676933.041661,6154972.539126)
director.addStrategy(QgsNetworkSpeedStrategy(10,1.0,1.0))
tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart])
graph = builder.graph()

startId = graph.findVertex(tiedPoints[0])
#endId = graph.findVertex(tiedPoints[1])

(tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, startId, 0)
```

P.S. The shortest path algorithm is working in the toolbox (predefine network analysis functions)

Comment: I am too getting the same results in 3.12. Essentially QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra() is returning an array 0f -1s [-1, -1, ...].

Comment: To add to my previous comment. In facte is the builder.graph() that doesn't seem to behave. graph.edgeCount() returns 0 i.e. no edges; graph.vertexCount() returns a plausible number of vertices.